# Batch file to copy newer folder to other location

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write a batch file that will copy newest folder from one location to another.

In folder name `DIR1` every day system is making backup and creating new folder in it (for example `ABC backup 01_10_2019`) with 2 files in it.
I have over 100 folders in that map (`DIR1`) so i need to copy only newest folder to another location.

I need to script copy only newest folder from `DIR1` and to `DIR2`

So far I have this but it doesn't work:

```
FOR /F "delims=|" %%I IN ('DIR "C:\DIR1" /B /AD /O:D') DO SET NewestFile=%%I
xcopy "C:\DIR1\%NewestFile%" "C:\DIR2" /E /H /K /Y
pause
```

---

Script for copying folder works great but I can't make script delete files older than 3 days because script is coping file from `NAS1` to `NAS2`.

In script:

```
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR "\\NAS1\" /B /AD /O-D') DO SET "Latest=%%~I" & goto :done
:done
robocopy "\\NAS01\%Latest%" "\\nas02\backup\%Latest%" /MIR
Rem till here crups works
Rem tried
forfiles -p "\\nas02\backup" -s -m *.* -D 3 -C "cmd /c del @path"
Rem error UNC paths are not supported.
Rem tried
forfiles -p "\\nas02\backup" -d -3 -c "cmd /c IF @isdir == TRUE rd /S /Q @path"
Rem error UNC paths are not supported
Rem Can anyone help me please
Pause
```

Comment: What exactly *"doesn't work"*? Please read [mcve]!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set it to latest folder first, set variable and exit the loop, then use `robocopy` to do the work.

```
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR "C:\DIR1" /B /AD /O-D') DO SET "Latest=%%~I" & goto :done
:done
robocopy "C:\DIR1\%Latest%" "C:\DIR2\%Latest%" /MIR
pause
```

Comment: It works.... awsome!! 
If i wont to delete older folder then ... let say 5 days... will this line be good:
forfiles /p "C:\DIR2" /s /m *.* /D -5 /C "cmd /c del @path"

Comment: No, to delete older files like that use `forfiles -p "C:\Dir1" -s -m *.* -d 5 -c "cmd /c del @path"` where you would be able to change the value `5` to the number of days you want.

Comment: ommg works great!!! Thank you very much.. trying to make this for a week...i forgot to use robocopy... thx m8...

Comment: I made same script for copying .7z files and delete them... works ok! i wounder what u think about it: its the same principle... having over 500 .7z backups but i wont to copy newest on other location nad after 3 days to delte old ones.. 
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('dir /b /a-d /od "c:dir1\*.7z"') do set "LatestModifiedFile=%%~i"
xcopy "c:dir1\%LatestModifiedFile%" "C:\dir2"
forfiles /p "C:dir2" /s /m *.7z /D -3 /C "cmd /c del @path"
pause

Comment: Im trying to delete folders older then 3 days on NAS... and conde dont recoqnize path... any ideas guys
useing: 
for /F "delims=" %%i IN ('DIR "C:\DIR1" /B /AD /O-D') DO SET "Latest=%%~I" & goto :done
:done
robocopy "C:\DIR1\%Latest%" "C:\DIR2\%Latest%" /MIR
forfiles -p "C:\DIR2" -s -m *.* -D 3 -C "cmd /c del @path"
pause
do u have any ideas